# Make SQL Calls on WindowsServices

Tags: c#, sql, windows-services

I'm making an application as follows: I have a webservice running on a local server, this webservice returns json like this:

```
[{"Id":1,"Titulo":"Live to win","Link":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/DPHlGVe8wxI","BandaId":1,"BandaNome":"Paul Stanley","GeneroId":1,"GeneroNome":"Rock","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":false},{"Id":2,"Titulo":"Welcome to the jungle","Link":null,"BandaId":2,"BandaNome":"Guns n´ roses","GeneroId":1,"GeneroNome":"Rock","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":2,"CriadorNome":"Usuário Teste","Ativo":true},{"Id":3,"Titulo":"Something just like this","Link":null,"BandaId":3,"BandaNome":"The Chainsmokers","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":true},{"Id":4,"Titulo":"Beliver","Link":null,"BandaId":4,"BandaNome":"Imagine Dragons","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":true},{"Id":5,"Titulo":"Radioactive","Link":null,"BandaId":4,"BandaNome":"Imagine Dragons","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":true},{"Id":6,"Titulo":"Friends - Original Mix","Link":null,"BandaId":5,"BandaNome":"Steener","GeneroId":2,"GeneroNome":"EDM","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":2,"CriadorNome":"Usuário Teste","Ativo":true},{"Id":7,"Titulo":"Amanheceu","Link":null,"BandaId":6,"BandaNome":"Scalene","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":2,"CriadorNome":"Usuário Teste","Ativo":true},{"Id":8,"Titulo":"Sonhador II","Link":null,"BandaId":6,"BandaNome":"Scalene","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":2,"CriadorNome":"Usuário Teste","Ativo":true},{"Id":9,"Titulo":"Amianto","Link":null,"BandaId":7,"BandaNome":"Supercombo","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":true},{"Id":10,"Titulo":"Monstros","Link":null,"BandaId":7,"BandaNome":"Supercombo","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":true},{"Id":11,"Titulo":"Piloto Automático","Link":null,"BandaId":7,"BandaNome":"Supercombo","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":2,"CriadorNome":"Usuário Teste","Ativo":true},{"Id":12,"Titulo":"Eutanásia","Link":null,"BandaId":7,"BandaNome":"Supercombo","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-23T16:42:54","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":true},{"Id":13,"Titulo":"Shots - Broiler Remix","Link":null,"BandaId":4,"BandaNome":"Imagine Dragons","GeneroId":3,"GeneroNome":"Indie","DtCriacao":"2017-03-24T16:55:46","CriadorId":1,"CriadorNome":"Márcio Eric","Ativo":true}]
```

But now I need to create a Windows Services that communicates with this WebService and what it receives in a database, I spent all day doing this webservice in several ways, but I did not find anything about good practices with webservices or etc. I'll show you what I did, but I'd like some tips on windows services, thank you

Here is my code

**Service:**

```
private Timer _worker;
    private readonly int _interval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timer"]);
    private readonly string _connection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"];
    //private readonly Connector _usuarioConnector;
    private readonly Connector _bandaConnector;
    //private readonly Connector _generoConnector;
    private readonly Connector _musicaConnector;
    private SqlConnection conn;

    public Service1()
    {
        //_usuarioConnector = new Connector("UsuarioBase");
        _bandaConnector = new Connector("BandaBase");
        //_generoConnector = new Connector("GeneroBase");
        _musicaConnector = new Connector("MusicaBase");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _worker = new Timer((Update), null, 0, _interval);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }

    private void Update(Object state)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           _connection))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Genero(nome, descricao, dtcriacao, criadorid, ativo) values('teste', 'teste', getdate(), 1, 1)", connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Query executada", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
        }
    }
```

**Loader**

```
public class Loader
{
    public static List<Usuario> LoadUsuarios(Connector usuarioConnector)
    {
        return (List<Usuario>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(usuarioConnector.GetData(), typeof(List<Usuario>));
    }
    public static List<Banda> LoadBandas(Connector bandaConnector)
    {
        var bandasDtos = (List<BandaDto>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bandaConnector.GetData(), typeof(List<BandaDto>));
        return bandasDtos.Select(dto => dto.ConvertToBanda()).ToList();
    }
    //public static List<Genero> LoadGeneros(Connector generoConnector)
    //{
        //var musicasDtos = (List<MusicaDto>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(musicaConnector.GetData(), typeof(List<MusicaDto>));
        //return musicasDtos.Select(dto => dto.ConvertToMusica()).ToList();
    //}
    public static List<Musica> LoadMusicas(Connector musicaConnector)
    {
        var musicasDtos = (List<MusicaDto>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(musicaConnector.GetData(), typeof(List<MusicaDto>));
        return musicasDtos.Select(dto => dto.ConvertToMusica()).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Connector**

```
 private string Host { get; }
    private WebRequest _request;
    public WebResponse Response;
    public string ConnectionStatus;
    private Stream _dataStream;
    private StreamReader _reader;

    public Connector(string config)
    {
        Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[config];

    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        StartConnection();
        _dataStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
        _reader = new StreamReader(_dataStream);
        var toReturn = _reader.ReadToEnd();
        EndConnection();
        return toReturn;
    }

    private void StartConnection()
    {
        _request = WebRequest.Create(Host);
        _request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Response = _request.GetResponse();
        ConnectionStatus = (((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusDescription);
    }

    private void EndConnection()
    {
        _reader.Close();
        Response.Close();
    }
```

**Edit1** In the current code it is doing a select, however in what I intend to do it will do inserts

Comment: In your Update method, you are doing a select statement, not an update.

Comment: I knew I was doing a select, at that point I was testing, but okay, I updated anyway.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: Simple, does not work, I have compiled several times, installed and uninstalled my machine, tried to debug with the EventLogs, however when I open a connection pool it does not even execute the WriteEntry

Comment: There is no reason to create the SqlConnection in OnStart. Just create, open, & close in Update. I'd also format your code a bit differently. Take a look at the CreateCommand example in the following MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, the service just stopped working, I saw it, read it, did it, but did not execute the query, I edited it for what I did there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139518/discussion-between-marcio-eric-and-william-xifaras).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered, unfortunately the timer was not working, so I just changed it to a thread.